# Linux Mint Not Updating

Tags: linux-mint, package-management

I literally installed it last night. This morning I saw an update icon but when I click Update Manager it says

> ERROR###ERROR###ERROR###ERROR###ERROR###ERROR###ERROR E:Encountered a
>   section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_petra_import_i18n_Translation-en,
>   E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Does anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Run `apt-get update` (as root, `sudo ...`).  If it doesn't correct it, remove the file and run the update again.

Answer (score 0):

What the other answer says.

In rather more detail: I'd suggest firstly, you do an APT clean-up, and then secondly, you do a full system upgrade from the shell.

## 1: Clean-up

sudo apt-get clean ; sudo apt-get autoclean ; sudo apt-get purge ; sudo apt-get autoremove -y

## 2: Full update

sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y

Then reboot. I suspect you'll find your errors in the GUI update tool will have gone. I'd had similar issues with Mint's GUI updater myself & now I preferentially use the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Then if the installer is still there, click the update icon. It should work. If it does not try using some clean out commands (e.g. `sudo apt-get update` is the most basic cleaning utility). You might also want to check your apt sources(I believe they are in `/etc/apt/sources.list`).